# Is there anyway to get the value of a disabled mat-autocomplete form-control in angular-material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have below `mat-form-field` **HTML** code

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" [matAutocomplete]="countryAutoComplete" 
              formControlName="country" [disabled]="true"> 
            <mat-autocomplete #countryAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filterOncountryList | async" [value]="item"> 
                {{item.CountryName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

The thing is that I have kept it **disabled on `ngOnInit()`**

```
  this.vendorDetails.controls['country'].disable();
```

and I have **by default** set a value like below

```
vendorDetails = new FormGroup({
accountGroupName: new FormControl(Validators.required),
country: new FormControl({ CountryName: "India", CountryCode: "IN" }, Validators.required),
});
```

On Submit of form, I need to fetch all the values but I am getting an error on this line.

```
if(this.vendorDetails.value.country.CountryCode == null ||  this.vendorDetails.value.country.CountryCode == ''){
  this.setCountryError = setErrors.errormsg.countryErrorMsg;
  this.vendorDetails.controls['country'].setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
  regError = true;
}
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'CountryCode' of undefined

On debugging, I am unable to see country form control.

Comment: make a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: How your fetching FormGroup's value? Try to use `this.vendorDetails.getRawValues()` method. Refer this for more http://azanebrain.github.io/news/angular-snafoo-form-value-vs-getrawvalues/

Comment: On which line are you getting this error? Post that line of code in the question.

Comment: I was fetching the values as below if(this.vendorDetails.value.country.CountryCode == null ||  this.vendorDetails.value.country.CountryCode == ''){
      regError = true;
    } changed it to .getRawValues(), getting the values now...thanks

Comment: In javascript, always use === and not ==.

Comment: try this this.vendorDetails.getRawValue()